# Failing to decompress streaming data by using UDF on Azure Databricks - Python

Tags: python, pyspark, binary, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I am trying to read Azure EventHub GZIP compressed messages using Azure DataBricks and python (PySpark), but using UDF isn't working with BinaryType data.

Well, here is the part where I check what is in the body

```
df = eventHubStream.withColumn("body", eventHubStream["body"]).select("body")
display(df, truncate=False)
```

And that displays a well compressed data, just like the following: `H4sIAKeM0FwC/3VS22rbQBB9z1cIQ6ElWN37JW8baeMKZEmRNk4LhcXUppg2cYncy...`

However when I try to send the data to my UDF, It doesn't behave like expected. The function literally don't do anything, but the output looks like it has been transformed:

```
import zlib
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def streamDecompress(val: BinaryType()):
  #return zlib.decompress(val)
  return val

func_udf = udf(lambda x: streamDecompress(x), StringType())

df = eventHubStream.withColumn("body", func_udf(eventHubStream["body"])).select("body")
display(df, truncate=False)
```

Here is the output:

```
[B@49d3f786
```

So, like expected, it fails when I try to decompress using zlib.

Anyone know how I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was way simpler than I thought. I was basically, trying to display a byte-like data haha.

The code below solved the problem:

```
import zlib

def streamDecompress(val):   
  return str(zlib.decompress(val, 15+32))

func_udf = udf(lambda x: streamDecompress(x))

df = eventHubStream.withColumn("body", func_udf(eventHubStream["body"])).select('body')

display(df, truncate=False)
```

Comment: you could simplify that (i think), but one question.. what does the 15+32 do?! seems magic, but i see it's related in some way to headers and checksum from some other googling about... still weird mind you!

Comment: As described in the docs right here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html on the decompress section: "+40 to +47 = 32 + (8 to 15): Uses the low 4 bits of the value as the window size logarithm, and automatically accepts either the zlib or gzip format."

Comment: This is already very simple. I am not really sure if we can really simplify that. But one thing that you can do is to remove the explicit UDF declaration and make it implicit:

@udf
def streamDecompress(value):     
  return str(zlib.decompress(value, 15+32))

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for this. As I've been struggling the last week to do the same with zStandard, thought I'd add my code snippet in case anyone else is looking for a similar solution (which I couldn't find anywhere):

```
import zstandard as zstd
def streamDecompress(val):
    return str(zstd.ZstdDecompressor().decompress(val))

my_udf=udf(lambda x: streamDecompress(x))
decompressedStream= pyStreamIn.withColumn("body",my_udf(pyStreamIn["body"]))
```